# Sync iTunes library across two machines

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, rsync

I would like to sync my music library across both my Macs. (one way sync from Machine A to Machine B)
I currently already am able to sync across the music itself using rsync, however I would also like to sync the iTunes libraries which consists of the files being synced.

So to be clear, I have two copies of the files.. one on each system. I do not want a central based system they must be independent from each other as they may not have contact with each other at all times.

I have tested by simply syncing across the iTunes library database and making sure that the file paths for each file is correct however iTunes does not pickup any of the files.

Anyone else done this or know of a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

What about using [iTunes Match](http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/)? One iTunes library across several Macs/iPhones/iPads?!

Comment: This is stored in the cloud (i.e. the internet), machine B may not have access to the internet at all times... plus I'm too cheap to pay for it anyway lol

Comment: Have you maybe tried using the Folder **Automatically Add To iTunes**. It's in your iTunes library folder. Maybe you could combine it with a little Apple script that after syncing the file would get deleted?

Comment: Thats a partial solution, I need it to copy over playlists as well

Comment: Okay. I would suggest, you use very specific Smart Playlists that you set up in both iTunes libraries with the same settings.

Or you try implementing this part (http://support.apple.com/kb/ta47831) in an Apple Script? Could potentially solve it.