# Can I sync itunes between my two mac laptops?

Tags: itunes, mac, data-synchronization

I want to download a music CD into itunes.  My new Mac doesn't have a disk drive, whereas my old one does.  Can I sync my laptops together so that I can get the music from the CD onto the new Mac laptop?

Or... is there another way I can move the files successfully into the itunes on my new Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Sign in to both computers with iTunes home sharing - then you can import files back and forth as needed. There is a filter to show songs not on the local library and the copying is drag and drop.

Much faster if you really want to copy files than iTunes Match which also would sync things, but take far longer to upload and download the files.

See these posts for some less useful options and extra commentary:

- [How can I sync my iTunes music library between two Macs for free?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/)
- [Sync iTunes library across two machines](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113002/)
- [Sync iTunes library with Dropbox without letting iTunes organize the folders and files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131333/)

Answer (score 0):

The best native software solution would be to sign up for iTunes Match on your older Mac that has a disk drive, then sign in on your new Mac.

Apple's iTunes Match puts all your music into the cloud, attached to your associated Apple ID using iCloud. You'll be able to play music from your old Mac, on your new Mac, and vice versa.

Even better, iTunes Match will take music you've ripped from CD's and replace it with the best possible audio quality from Apple's servers.

For more information about iTunes Match, visit this page: http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/

Comment: The additional expense of iTunes Match isn't needed.  As the other answer available now indicates, just set up home sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also [setup a Remote Disc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203973) on the Mac with an CD/DVD reader:

> - On the Mac that has an optical drive, choose System Preferences from the Apple menu.
> - Click the Sharing icon in the System Preferences window.
> - Make sure you've entered a name that you can easily recognize in the Computer Name field.
> - Enable the checkbox for DVD or CD Sharing.
>
> You can also restrict who has access to your optical drive by
>   selecting "Ask me before allowing others to use my DVD drive."

This adds a virtual CD / DVD reader to your Mac, in case you need it for other uses than CD ripping.